# NetBeans Installation

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

Is it true that **just** JDK version 7 could be used to install NetBeans IDE 8.0.2? 
On my device, I have been installed the last version of JDK, but while I am installing Netbeans, a message appeared to tell that I have to install JDK. In other words, Netbeans didn't recognize that there is already a JDK and successfully installed !!

Comment: Why are you installing such an outdated NetBeans version?

Comment: What version of JDK 7 are you using? Be very specific, because it matters. From the [8.02 installation instructions](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/install.html): _"The Java SE Development Kit (JDK) **7 Update 10 (or later)** or JDK 8 is required to install NetBeans IDE."_.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans 8.0 runs just fine with Java 8.

If NetBeans doesn't detect or find your JDK, you can always provide the location on the command line when starting NetBeans, e.g.:

```
netbeans64.exe --jdkhome c:\Java8
```

I have never used the NetBeans installer, but I think you can pass that parameter to the installer as well.

---

Once, installed, you can also edit conf/netbeans.conf and un-comment the line `#netbeans_jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"` and make it point to your JDK:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="c:\Java8"
```

Comment: I will try it. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

> The Java SE Development Kit (JDK) 7 Update 10 (or later) or JDK 8 is required to install NetBeans IDE.

As seen on [NetBeans 8.0.2 Installation Instructions](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/install.html) it seems you really have to be on JDK 7 or 8.

While installing one of those versions, remind yourself to set the PATH variable.

Comment: @torbleone Big thanks for you. I will try this solution.